# Embedded Python in C++ cannot import pandas twice

Tags: python, c++, pandas

I'm embedding Python 3.8.2 in C++ code (using Visual Studio 2019). Python has pandasn installed (through pip).

I manage to import pandas from a C++ program, however, when I try to import it a second time, it crashs.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    {
        Py_SetPythonHome( L"C:\\Python38" );

        // Initialize the Python Interpreter
        Py_Initialize();

        std::cout << "Importing pandas..." << std::endl;
        if ( PyRun_SimpleString( "import pandas" ) == 0 )
            std::cout << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;

        Py_Finalize();
    }

    {
        Py_SetPythonHome( L"C:\\Python38" );

        // Initialize the Python Interpreter
        Py_Initialize();

        std::cout << "Importing pandas..." << std::endl;
        if ( PyRun_SimpleString( "import pandas" ) == 0 )
            std::cout << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;

        Py_Finalize();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This crashs with an exception:

```
_multiarray_umath.cp38-win_amd64.pyd!00007ffbd5b8ca69() Inconnu
_multiarray_umath.cp38-win_amd64.pyd!00007ffbd5b8ffd6() Inconnu
_multiarray_umath.cp38-win_amd64.pyd!00007ffbd5b9d34d() Inconnu
python38.dll!00007ffbd22f6131() Inconnu
python38.dll!00007ffbd22f6092() Inconnu
```

Output is:

```
Importing pandas...
SUCCESS
Importing pandas...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
```

Is there any init/uninit step I missed that could make this fail while it shaould work?

Note that I cannot Debug as pandas [cannot be loaded in Debug build](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html#debug-build-on-windows).

Comment: This is something we noticed some years ago: `PyFinalize()` doesn't clean up the interpreter like expected. One symptom we observed: With every `PyInit()`, the Windows task manager reported an increasing amount of allocated memory even if there was effectively rather nothing between `PyInit()` and `PyFinalize()`. With Python libraries using DLLs internally, it's even more dramatically - like described in your question. 2nd init may fail or even crash.

Comment: We ended up with calling `PyInit()` exactly once at begin of the application (`PyFinalize()` at end respectively) and do our best to get rid of temp. stuff by nesting of our Python user code scripts internally in a wrapper function. (It's amazing that even in functions `import` can be used.) The only draw-back: The reported line numbers in trace-backs are a little bit shifted as the wrapper code (invisible to the user) is counted as well, of course.

Comment: Needless to say that we researched a while to solve the issue in a better way before but without luck. I noticed that this issue was popping up over the years again and again with varying Python versions. Somebody claimed it should be solved eventually but we still were able to observe it in our even more recent Python interpreter version. I'm even not sure whether the Python interpreter itself is really responsible for this. It might be caused by the imported modules with DLLs instead which might use globals and heap-allocated things internally which are never cleaned up.

Comment: @Scheff: Thanks, at least this is a nice workaround. Have you reported this to Python team? Is this a known issue?

Comment: @Scheff: Wierd stuff is that with only one import, there is no memory leak reported.

Comment: See my 2nd comment. It was reported again and again. And, (3rd comment) who knows if there is actually something which can be fixed in the interpreter for this. Btw. another solution could be to run the Python interpreter in its own `fork()` but we are on Windows and unfortunately don't have this option... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: By the way, if you do a single static `PyInit`, then it means that a script may use pandas without importing it if a previous script imported it? Also some global variables may interfer between scripts being executed?

Comment: The memory leaks may occur if the 2nd initialization happens where the heap-allocated data of the 1st initialization gets lost...

Comment: @Scheff: OK, thanks again, I'll go with the workaround except if someone proposes something better here!

Comment: The global variables were exactly the reason why we use an internal wrapper function. Due to this, there are no more global (Python) variables. They are all local in our wrapper function. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: Could you illustrate what you mean by this wrapper function? Maybe in an answer to that question?

Answer (score 2):

Upon request from OP, I made a small demo for how we wrap user Python scripts in our application to prevent that global variables of user scripts become unintended persistent:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Python.h>

const char *PyScript = R"(try:
  print(a)
except:
  print("a not (yet) defined")
a = 123
print(a)
)";

std::string wrapPyScript(const char* script)
{
  std::string source = std::string("def __mainPythonFunction():\n") + script;
  { const char *const indent = "\n  ";
    for (size_t i = source.size(); i--;) {
      size_t n = 1;
      switch (source[i]) {
        case '\n': if (i && source[i - 1] == '\r') n = 2, --i;
        case '\r': source.replace(i, n, indent); break;
      }
    }
  }
  source += "\n"
    "pass\n"
    "\n"
    "try:\n"
    "  __mainPythonFunction()\n"
    "except:\n"
    "  rf.form.appContext.notifyAbort()\n"
    "  raise\n";
  return source;
}
#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(Py_Initialize());
  std::cout << "\nWithout wrapper:\n\n";
  DEBUG(for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    DEBUG(PyRun_SimpleString(PyScript));
  });
  std::cout << "\nWith wrapper:\n\n";
  DEBUG(for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    DEBUG(PyRun_SimpleString(wrapPyScript(PyScript).c_str()));
  });
  std::cout << '\n';
  DEBUG(Py_Finalize());
}
```

Output:

```
Py_Initialize();

Without wrapper:

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { DEBUG(PyRun_SimpleString(PyScript)); };
PyRun_SimpleString(PyScript);
a not (yet) defined
123
PyRun_SimpleString(PyScript);
123
123

With wrapper:

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { DEBUG(PyRun_SimpleString(wrapPyScript(PyScript).c_str())); };
PyRun_SimpleString(wrapPyScript(PyScript).c_str());
a not (yet) defined
123
PyRun_SimpleString(wrapPyScript(PyScript).c_str());
a not (yet) defined
123

Py_Finalize();
```

However, I'm not quite sure whether this is enough to fix OPs issue with the imported Pandas library.

In our application (where we used the above trick), we import selected libraries once after the `Py_Initialize()`.
(I remember roughly that this was our last desperate resort to fix similar issues like OP observed.)

Comment: Thanks, I see the idea now. This helps, even if it's not really a solution, more a workaround, as discussed...